# Field error Cannot resolve keyword 'likes' into field. Choices are: id, name, page

Tags: python, linux, django

I am new to django.I am following the tutorial given in tangowithdjango.com.I don't know why the error is coming.........
The error is

```
Exception Type:     FieldError
Exception Value:    Cannot resolve keyword 'likes' into field. Choices are: id, name, page

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in names_to_path, line 1397
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.9
Python Path:    

['/root/workspace/tango_with_django',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-13.1.2-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']
```

My populate_rango.py file is

```
 import os
 os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tango_with_django.settings')
 import django
 django.setup()

 from rango.models import Category, Page


 def populate():
     python_cat = add_cat('Python')

     add_page(cat=python_cat,
       title="Official Python Tutorial",
       url="http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/"
       views=128,
       likes=64
       )

     add_page(cat=python_cat,
       title="How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
       url="http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/",
       views=128,
       likes=64)

     add_page(cat=python_cat,
       title="Learn Python in 10 Minutes",
       url="http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/",
       views=128,
       likes=64)

     django_cat = add_cat("Django")

     add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Official Django Tutorial",
        url="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/",
        views=64,
        likes=32)

     add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Django Rocks",
        url="http://www.djangorocks.com/",
        views=64,
        likes=32)

     add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="How to Tango with Django",
        url="http://www.tangowithdjango.com/",
        views=64,
        likes=32)

     frame_cat = add_cat("Other Frameworks")

     add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Bottle",
        url="http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/",
        views=32,
        likes=16)

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Flask",
        url="http://flask.pocoo.org",
        views=32,
        likes=16)


   for c in Category.objects.all():
    for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
        print "- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p))

  def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0,likes=0):
      p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title)[0]
      p.url=url
      p.views=views
      p.likes=likes
      p.save()
      return p

  def add_cat(name,views=0,likes=0):
      c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
      c.views=views
      c.likes=likes
      c.save()
      return c 


    if __name__ == '__main__':
       print "Starting Rango population script..."
        populate()
```

and admin.py file is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from rango.models import Category,Page
from rango.models import views,likes
# Register your models here.
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display=('title','category','url')
admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(views)
admin.site.register(likes)
admin.site.register(Page,PageAdmin)
```

The models.py is

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):  #For Python 2, use __str__ on Python 3
    return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()


    def __unicode__(self):      
        return self.title

class views(models.Model):
    number=models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.number

class likes(models.Model):
    num=models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.num
```

Please help me with the error.Thanks for spending some of your time...

Comment: Do you have a full traceback?

Comment: yeah.You want me to upload it?

Comment: What is meant by full traceback?I am new to django.So,i don't know exactly what it is.@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Can you show your models?

Comment: I have uploaded models.py @AlexLisovoy

Comment: Your model `likes` don't have any relationships with any models. You should specified it, choose from: Many-to-one, One-to-one, Many-to-many or generic

Comment: Can you upload the code please? @AlexLisovoy

Answer (score 0):

There is no `likes/views` field in `Page` or `Category` models. 
You need to first create a relation from `Page` and `Category` to `Likes` and `Views` model and then you can save the views and likes for a particular page or category.

I would suggest you to add the `likes` & `views` field in `Page` & `Category` model itself.

Instead of separate `Like` and `Views` model do like:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):  #For Python 2, use __str__ on Python 3
        return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

After adding the new fields to Page/Category table, do makemigrations and then migrate.

If you DROP Like/views table, just make sure that you remove all references to them in your views, admin.py etc..

Comment: I couldn't understand exactly.Can you upload the code? @Anush

Comment: why does he need likes in category model? I dont see any logic in it. it fits in page model rather

Comment: @doniyor In views he is trying to save views/likes for category as well so I added those fields.

Comment: Now,I am getting an error 'ImportError: cannot import name views' when I run the server.

Comment: @abhaygurrala remove `from rango.models import views,likes` from your admin.py

Comment: Their is no such type of code in my views and I am getting error in admin.py @Anush

Comment: oh sorry in your admin.py remove references to views and likes table.

Comment: @Anush i dont see any need for it. he should save likes only in pages object. category doesnot make sense

Comment: @doniyor I agree with you, I only added them after seeing his views.

Comment: @doniyor  Now getting an error 'NameError: name 'views' is not defined'.Please help me

Comment: @abhaygurrala in your views you are calling frame_cat = `add_cat("Django")` without passing the views or likes to the `add_cat(name,views,likes)` function, that might be the issue.

Comment: Still getting the same error.I changed frame_cat = add_cat("Django") to frame_cat = add_cat(name,views,likes)

Comment: @abhaygurrala there are to more function calls without passing views/likes  `python_cat = add_cat('Python')` and `frame_cat = add_cat("Other Frameworks")`. To solve this just set default values to views and likes in your `add_cat()` and `add_page()` functions like: 
`def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0,likes=0):` and `def add_cat(name,views=0,likes=0):`

Comment: @Anush Not solved :(.Can you update my populate_rango.py file and upload it?

Comment: @abhaygurrala check this link: https://shrib.com/3thY9slJaVEle4k?v=nc
 and in your `add_cat(...)` function you are assigning `c.likes=c` and `c.views=c` change them to `c.views=views` and `c.likes=likes`

Comment: @abhaygurrala can you update the populate_rango.py in your question with your current version.

Comment: @abhaygurrala You have not added a  **comma(,)** after initializing the **URL** in this function call: `add_page(cat=python_cat, title="Official Python Tutorial", url="http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/" views=128, likes=64)` -> there is no comma after initializing URL.
`